# What type of adhesive should I use to attach metal to vertical tile?

Tags: kitchens, tile, mounting, adhesive

I'd like to attach a magnetic, metal [knife rack](http://wholesale.norpro.com/index.php/15-s-s-magnetic-knife-bar.html) to a tile splashback in my kitchen. The tile is glazed white and the attachment points on the rack are small (about 0.9 sq in of metal). The rack weighs 2.5lb and with the knives and a margin for error, we're looking at about 5.25lbs total weight.

I've been looking at Loctite, Gorilla Glue, and everything Henkel makes, but I'm having trouble hitting:

- Works on metal & glazed tile
- Water resistant enough to be behind the sink
- Sets up quickly enough for a vertical application
- Removable (this is a rental)

I've looked at:

- Cyanoacrylate gel adhesives, but I can't tell if they can handle being sprayed with water.
- Epoxies, but they aren't removable.
- Polyurethane adhesives, but they don't work vertically.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure you want a bunch of knives held up by something NOT permanent.  You can use Command Strips but you better grab your knives quickly.

Comment: @DMoore I wouldn't go grabbing tumbling pieces of sharp metal, either way you can ask if you can drill the holes for the mounting points

Comment: I would just like to point out that any adhesive strong enough to do this, will likely damage, discolor or otherwise change the appearance of the tile. So if you're trying to avoid damage or losing a deposit, etc. Then maybe it's time to look for a standing magnetic rack.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to install something like that without mechanical fasteners I'd try a product called Lexel. It's silicone based so it's good in wet conditions and sticks to pretty much anything, but it gets harder than traditional silicone so it forms a bond that's scary strong. Having said that, relying solely on an adhesive in an application like this is not recommendable. Ceramic tile is really good at not letting stuff stick to it,  and a falling knife rack is the stuff of my nightmares. A couple hollow wall anchors will buy you a lot of piece of mind.